# Case for range of numbers excluding specific number - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have this query

```
SELECT * ,
CASE WHEN FigureID >= 0 AND <= 10 AND <> 5
THEN 'Group1' ELSE 'Group2' END AS 'Group'
FROM
Figure
```

Now i am looking to include all numbers between 1-10 in the case statement but exclude 5. Is there anyway to do so that '5' is excluded specifically.

I have tried this but it still doesn't give me the result i am looking for.

```
 SELECT * ,
 CASE WHEN FigureID <= 4 AND FigureID >= 6
 THEN 'Group1' ELSE 'Group2' END AS 'Group'
 FROM
 Figure
```

Example result

```
FigureID    Amount  Group
   1          10    Group1
   2          10    Group1
   3          10    Group1
   4          10    Group1
   5          10    N/a
   6          10    Group1
```

SQL fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/30e2c/11

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the column name for each condition

```
    SELECT * ,
        CASE WHEN FigureID >= 0 AND FigureID <= 10 AND FigureID <> 5
             THEN 'Group1' 
             ELSE 'Group2' 
        END AS 'Group'
    FROM  Figure
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT * ,
    CASE WHEN (FigureID >= 1 AND FigureID <= 10) AND (FigureID <> 5)
    THEN 'Group1'
    WHEN FigureID = 5 THEN 'N/A' 
    ELSE 'Group2'
    END AS [Group]
    FROM Figure
```

First `CASE` takes care of the condition that FigureID is between 1 and 10 but not equal to 5 and the output is 'Group1'.

Second `CASE` tackles the situation where FigureID has a value of 5 and outputs 'N/A'

`ELSE` clause is if above two conditions are false and outputs 'Group2'.

Finally, this column's name is Group but since Group is a keyword we must enclose it within square braces like `[Group]`.

Comment: NP3 thanks. Please add some more explanation to this answer to help clarify it for the original poster. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your answer to improve it."

Comment: @micstr: Well I thought the code is self-explanatory to OP but you are right, I should add explanatory notes for others to understand. So I am editing my answer!

Comment: Agree with you NP3 - your code looked good *but* if you don't add a few words then your question can end up in the "Low quality posts" queue and risks your hard work being axed!

Answer (score 0):

Just use not equal to 5 instead

```
SELECT * ,
 CASE WHEN FigureID <> 5
 THEN 'Group1' 
when FigureID  =5
then 'n/a'
ELSE 'Group2' END AS 'Group'
 FROM
 Figure
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
(CASE WHEN FigureID >= 1 AND FigureID <= 10 AND FigureId <> 5
      THEN 'Group1'
      ELSE 'Group2'
 END) AS grp
```

You can also do:

```
(CASE WHEN FigureId = 5 THEN 'N/A'
      WHEN FigureID >= 1 AND FigureID <= 10 THEN 'Group1'
      ELSE 'Group2'
 END) AS grp
```

Also important:  Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Also, avoid using SQL keywords as identifier names (`GROUP` is a SQL keyword).